# factory girl error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

I am getting an error when I'm running my test file.

```
factory.rb:334:in `factory_by_name': No such factory: user (ArgumentError)
```

I have the user model but still why am getting this error?
My factories.rb contains:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do |u|
    u.sequence(:email) {|n| "#{n}@email.com"}
    u.login 'Joe'
    u.password 'password'
    u.password_confirmation 'password'
    u.phone '1111111111'
    u.gender 'F'
    u.active '1'
    u.social_profile_active '1'
  end
end
```

in `test_helper.rb`

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require 'factory_girl'
#Factory.find_definitions

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.(yml|csv) for all tests in alphabetical order.
  #
  # Note: You'll currently still have to declare fixtures explicitly in integration tests
  # -- they do not yet inherit this setting
  #fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end
```

my ruby version is 1.8.7 and rails3.0.1

And my gemfile looks like this:
group :test do
  gem 'shoulda'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'mocha'
end

Comment: where is your factory file stored?

Comment: its in Test Files/Factories/factories.rb

Answer (score 1):

Rename your directory to one of the following:

> Factories can be defined anywhere, but will be automatically loaded if
> they are defined in files at the following locations:
>
> test/factories.rb
>
> spec/factories.rb
>
> test/factories/*.rb
>
> spec/factories/*.rb

https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md

Comment: One more doubt is am using ruby 1.8.7 and rails 301 and when i install factory_girl_rails3 its showing an error that it can be used for ruby 1.9..what should i do now?

Comment: switch to ruby 1.9 or install an old version of factory_girl_rails.. Did you try if it works with my solution above?

Comment: No, Its not working and i installed factory_girl_rails 1.2. But still am facing the same issue :(

Comment: the directories above are maybe case sensitive.. did you check that? also if you use an old version of factory_girl_rails you have to use maybe an older syntax..

Comment: May i know where can i find the older syntax ?

Comment: i think you have to look into the sourcecode and read the commments